# CommandLineParser: get Name of Mutually Exclusive Options Set

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-parser

Using [CommandLineParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/) I can define a set of mutually exclusive options like this (taken from the [wiki](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/wiki/Mutually-Exclusive-Options)):

```
class OptionsMutuallyExclusive
{
  //define commands in set(group) named web
  [Option(SetName = "web")]
  public string DocumentRoot { get; set; }
  [Option(SetName  = "web")]
  public bool EnableJavaScript { get; set; }

  //define other commands in set(group) named ftp
  [Option(SetName  = "ftp")]
  public string FtpDirectory { get; set; }
  [Option(SetName  = "ftp")]
  public bool AnonymousLogin { get; set; }

  //Common: the next option can be used with any set because it's not included in a set
  [Option('r')]
  public string UrlAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can parse this my app like this (`.Dump()` coming from LinqPad)

```
var result = parser.ParseArguments<OptionsMutuallyExclusive>(args);
result.WithParsed(options => options.Dump()).WithNotParsed(errs => errs.Dump());
```

And will get a positive result (`WithParsed`) using the following args:

```
--enablejavascript --documentroot ~/var/local/website -r http://localhost
--ftpdirectory ~/var/local/ftpsite --anonymouslogin -r ftp://myftp.server
```

And will get an error (`WithNotParsed`) on this:

```
--enablejavascript --anonymouslogin
```

**But:** Is there any way to tell, which set was used?

So getting the value `web` on the first call and the value `ftp` on the second one? Or by using an interface and/or derived classes getting an typed result like `WebOptions` and `FtpOptions`?

Using different classes I can call `ParseArguments` multiple times until it succeeds but this isn't really nice.

All examples I could find are always trying to determine the current set by testing which values are defined and which are not.

Is there any thing I'm missing?

Any alternative?